# Relational Personal Media Explorer

Tags: windows, database, document-management, media-manager

I want a windows 8 compatible program that will help me track my media collection in a way that helps me keep track of files and will support relations.

Currently, I am using Tabbles to tag files with multiple tags.  This is much better than the standard the Windows file hierarchy in that I can quickly find files with multiple attributes.  Where this approach fails is that to tag a file with complex attributes I would have to create very specific tags that would be used in very few other circumstances.  For example, if I want to tag files with starring actors/actresses and their age during their performance I would need to create new tag for every possible value.  As I approach thousands of unique tags this becomes unwieldy.

My ideal solution would

1. be available on multiple operating systems
2. be free (who doesn't like free?)
3. be open-source
4. provide a UI (or the tools to create one) for adding and searching files.
5. require minimal coding from me.
6. support customized attributes

**Edit**: I've discovered Kexi which seems to be what I want except that it no longer supports Windows.  I started to use Open Office Base but I just discovered that it doesn't really support storing links to files.